# Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is not present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, get

```
DISCLAIMER: This question is a question about question. So that makes this question a meta question. It does not have any connection to the previously asked questions. If you find any resemblance, lemme tell you one thing- it's purely coincidental.
```

I want to make an AJAX request from my web page. I have been trying to do this, but none of the methods worked perfectly. The only post that I found something close to reality is [this](http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/2772/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requeste).

I tried various other methods from SO & other similar sites, but all of those posts said only one thing to me.

```
"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."
```

I know now you are gonna mark this question as duplicate since there are loads of questions similar to this. Now..Lemme tell ya' one thing. I tried every piece of sh*t I found in SO, but none of 'em gave me the result that I was looking for. It's not because they all are wrong. It because I ain't got no knowlegde on how to use 'em. Then finally...I settled on the link I provided above. It's easy..but I need to know certain things about the code.This is the first time I am hearing the beautifully sodding acronym- CORS. So, if anyone can help me understand the questions I raise, Up votes for all of ya'. I wanna resolve this son-of-a-b*tch question before I celebrate my birthday for the third time this year. I will tell ya' what all I have-in form of resources & questions.

```
1) A rotten server located at Elizabeth town.
2) I need to access it.
3) I am planning to make a HTTP GET request.
4) I have a url. (eg. http://whereismyweed.com)
5) I store it into a JavaScript variable. var stoner='http://whereismyweed.com'
6) I have a HTML div tag in my webpage. (<div id="myprecious"></div>)
7) I wanna display the response I get from the server inside of 'myprecious' div.
8) And last but not the least... my AJAX function. (Courtesy: some website I visited)




$.ajax({
                url: stoner,
                    data: myData,
                    type: 'GET',
                    crossDomain: true, // enable this
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    success: function() { alert("Success"); },
                error: function() { alert('Failed!'); },
                beforeSend: setHeader
            });
```

What is 'myData'?? What does it contain. How can I get the response for this request? What is 'setHeader'?? Does it have any significance??? How can I display the response inside myprecious div? What changes should I make in the function? Is this function correct?

Too many question, Right???? Well...I need only one common answer for it?

Comment: the server at "Elizabeth town", needs to grant you access to it. HTTP speaking, the server needs to send in the header a property called `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` with the value of `*` (for all requests from all websites) or the domain name, like `http://foo.domain.com` that will only allow `http://foo.domain.com`  to perform requests.

Comment: Is this what you are talking about?? Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * ???
var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);
xhr.setRequestHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
xhr.send(); 


Reference: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ @balexandre

Comment: it's the server that needs to send **in the response**... not you to the server! You can't do anything from just your side. This insures that you own or have permissions to such server.

Answer (score -1):

Your function is correct.Follow below steps do achieve your goal-

```
 //for getting response modify your code like 

      success:function(response){
            alert(response);
            $('#myprecious').html(response); //myprecious is id of div
     }

  // myData variable is jSon object which contains request parameter has to send.Eg.
     var myData = {'first_name':'Foo','last_name':'Bar'}  // now on server first_name and last_name treated as request parameter.


  // If server not required any special headers to validate request 'setHeader' does not require. by default $.ajax will take care of it. you can remove it.



     /// final code looks like 


         $.ajax({
            url: stoner,
                data: myData, 
                type: 'GET',
                crossDomain: true, // enable this
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function(response ) { $('#myprecious').html(response);    
  },
                error: function() { alert('Failed!'); }

        });
```

Comment: When I run this script 'Failed!' is the output I get. How to add special headers to validate the request??? @Vicky

Comment: first you have to determine  which special header is required. Add header -> beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Test-Header', 'test-value'); xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Test-Header2', 'test-value2'); and so on }